# windows and osx server behind 1 external ip

Tags: mac, windows-server-2008, osx-server

I have a mac server and a windows server behind and sonicwall with one external ip address.  Currently, all http traffic points to the windows server. I've tried to figure out a way to redirect traffic from a subdomain to my apple server (apple.mysite.com), and even tried to do port changes mysite.com:1919.  I'm able to get to the server site [os x server landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt5ZA.png)

with the port change method.  Whenever I click a link or try to navigate to mysite.com:1919/mydevices I get a redirect error.

I've even tried this article from sonicwall: [sonicwall article](https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw5611)

Is there a accepted practice of trying to do this without getting another external ip address?  Can I redirect traffic with the windows server to a mac server?

Comment: You may want to install on OSX `HAProxy` and setup it such way so it can distinguish traffic by external domain (www1.TLD -> OSX, and www.TLD -> windows). This way you can forward all traffic to port 80 to OSX and depend on sub-domain HAProxy will manage traffic  where is goes

Comment: I will try the reverse proxy idea on the windows side since they are already the public facing sites. [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1189047.aspx?One+Public+IP+2+internal+servers)

Comment: Yes, any reverse proxy solutions such as HAproxy or via IIS should work

Comment: I ran into another problem with the reverse proxy. [See question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025985/reverse-proxy-windows-server-too-many-redirects0).